# How can I make the image stay within certain bounds while also floating?

Tags: css, html, wordpress

I have a (WordPress) page on which there are a list of different programs. On the left-hand side is a text description of the program and on the right is an image. Back in the day I would have used a table to make this happen:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Text goes here.</td>
    <td><img src="myimage.jpg"></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Now I am trying to align it w/out tables:

```
<p style="text-align: left">Text goes here.</p>
<img class="alignright size-medium wp-image-119" src="imageurl.jpg" width="300" height="199" />
<hr>
```

Problem is that if there isn't enough text, the image begins to take up space in the next program's section. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screen capture of image alignment issue]

You can see that the placeholder image is not remaining above the HR and beginning to slide into the next program's segment. How can I prevent this?

Comment: [**JSFiddle, if you please.**](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the `table` `display` model:

```css
p {
  display:table;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
p span {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
  <span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/199"/></span></p>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Isn't he trying to do it specifically without tables though?

Comment: @David, where do you see a table ?

Comment: this is  CSS . It has nothing to do with HTML. it is the defaut value of the tag <table>, nothing more or less :) http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display  and http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/

Comment: Ok. no worries. Just trying to understand your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would use `ul` and `li` to get the job done.

```
<ul id="program_list">
     <li id="program_item" class="item01">
          // HTML for program item goes here
     </li>
     <li id="program_item" class="item02">
          // HTML for program item goes here
     </li>
</ul>
```

Then you would use some CSS to set the width of the `ul` and make sure that each `li` is the full width, and does not `float` the next item, with this you could also so a `border-bottom:` to separate each program.

```
#program_list {
     width: 600px;
}

#program_item {
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     float: none;
     padding: 10px 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}
```

Assuming you have already cleared your CSS initially; if not, you may have to add more CSS to style correctly.

Comment: actually <picture> and <figcaption> would be appropriate , not li ;)  http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

Comment: @GCyrillus I think it almost does the same thing, it's really just a preference. I prefer to use lists.